# Glassfish 2.1 classpath-prefix or classpath-suffix not loading

Tags: glassfish-2.x

Hope you can help me here, I am trying to add some new jars to the classpath of the glasspath, but they just fail to load up.

I am using glassfish 2.1

Here's the snippet when the server is started

-Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathPrefix=../grops/lib/grops-4.3.5.jar;../grops/lib/iaik_jce_full_3.13.jar;../grops/config
-Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathSuffix=
-Dcom.sun.aas.ServerClassPath=

Snippet from my domain.xml

java-config classpath-suffix="../grops/lib/grops-4.3.5.jar${path.separator}../grops/lib/iaik_jce_full_3.13.jar${path.separator}../grops/config${path.separator}../grops/lib/zmd-security-LU2.jar${path.separator}../grops/lib/db2jcc.jar${path.separator}../grops/lib/db2jcc_javax.jar${path.separator}..........

I have tried from admin console and also changing directly in domain.xml , they just dont load up and always throw an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by myself, actually whenever we add something to the classpath newly a new command window has to be used to restart the glassfish server:

ex run-->cmd--> cd C:\glassfish\bin
asadmin --> start-domain xxx

This has to be done by closing the previous command window after stopping the server by stop-domain because everytime you run asadmin command, asenv is called which sets the new parameters to the JVM.